# Am I able to use Content Staging with PWA Studio?

Tags: magento2, admin, pwa-studio

I'm creating a new PWA Studio setup using Adode Commerce Cloud 2.4.6. Am I able to set up and use Content Staging objects and campaigns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and schedule the updates but can't preview them.

The content will be served via APIs when the schedule activates it. However, the preview needs to be implemented in the frontend. It just has API support.

[image: Content Staging with PWA Studio?]

Reference: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/integrations/adobe-commerce/features/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in 2019 they acknowledged this feature request: https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues/1160

Can't access the internal Jira though.